# Is it possible to download only a certain percentage of a file wit Kget (or wget)?

Tags: linux, download, wget, kde

I need to download some large files (ISOs of some Linux distros) and I'm connected to the internet with a mobile broadband connection, which has a limited amount of daily total data transfer size.

I'd like to set up Kget (or alternatively wget) to download only a certain part of a specific file at a time (i.e., only 100MB of a said ISO) to make sure to not exceed my daily quota and resume it the next day, and without having to continuously checking by myself.

Is it possible to do that, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, if it is possible for you to use cURL instead of wget, you can use

`curl --range startByte-stopByte "URL to some ISO-file"`

the manpage can help you: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 0):

Not with `wget` atleast...You can limit the download speed by using `--limit-rate=amount` flag but cannot limit its daily bandwidth usage.

maybe [Flareget](http://flareget.com/) or [FatRat](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/) can help you